# animate only the appended text with show("slow")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

in this code: http://jsfiddle.net/GeAwB/, I would like to animate the last appended content using jquery show("slow") for example.

I put the new content in some div new_div:

```
<div id="new_div" ></div>
```

and add this in the main div "shanon"-div:

```
         <div id="shanon" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

The Problem ist, the whole main div "shanon"-div will be animated, I want only the last added row to be animated.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

http://jsfiddle.net/GeAwB/6/

you should wrap every row with an element like for my example, i wrapped every row with a 
`div`

then in your javascript.. find the last div element. then animate it....

```
$("#shanon").append($("#new_div").html()).find("div").last().hide().show("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility that doesn't mess with your line spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/GeAwB/18/

Answer (score 1):

Each time the button is clicked, create a new div rather than trying to reuse `<div id="new_div"></div>`

Code will simplify quite considerably and becomes much easier to follow

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $new_div, $shanon = $("#shanon"),
        $weiter = $("#weiter"),
        $zeile = $(".zeile");
    $weiter.removeAttr("disabled").click(function() {
        if (i < array.length) {
            if (i > 0) {
                $zeile.removeClass("zeile");
            }
            $new_div = $("<div/>").html(array[i]).hide().appendTo($shanon).show("slow");
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else {
            $zeile.removeClass("zeile");
            $weiter.attr("disabled", "disabled");

        }
    });
});
```

See [update of fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeAwB/19/)

*EDIT: removal of `zeile` class is not quite right. `$('.zeile')` needs to be put back inside the click handler. I'll not bother doing the change as another answer has been accepted, albeit inefficient.*